# XML passed as param to XSL and cannot convert to node set using Datapower

Tags: xml, xslt

I pass the following XML as a param into my XSL below (via Java).

```
<roles><role>USA</role><role>GB</role><role>EU</role></roles>
```

I cannot get it to evaluate but if I define the exact same xml string inside a variable it works fine.

I am using Datapower.

Here's my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
>

<xsl:param name="roles"/>

<xsl:variable name="roles2"><roles><role>USA</role><role>GB</role><role>EU</role></roles></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:if test="exslt:node-set($roles)/roles/role = 'GB'">
        YES 1
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="exslt:node-set($roles2)/roles/role = 'GB'">
        YES 2
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$roles2/roles/role = 'GB'">
        YES 3
    </xsl:if>

    roles = <xsl:value-of select="$roles" />
    roles2 = <xsl:value-of select="$roles2" />

</xsl:template>
```

When I run it I get the following output:

```
YES 2 YES 3 roles = <roles><role>USA</role><role>GB</role><role>EU</role></roles> roles2 = USAGBEU
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening and how to fix it to YES 1 appears?

Thanks.

Comment: The invoker of the transformation must parse (load) the string and produce as result an XML document *object*. This is the object that must be passed as the `roles` parameter.

Comment: I'm working with @user1810292 on this problem. So I'm presuming its not possible to do this and there is no workaround? thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass it in as a parameter it's a string value, not a node set.  i.e. it is not being parsed as XML.  AFAIK there's no way to make this happen on XSLT1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exsl:node-set to overcome this problem.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SO and thank you for helping! Consider adding details on how this solution solves the issue. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .